# ArrayBlockingQueue showing weired behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

i was studdying BlockingQueue  interface of which ArrayBlockingQueue is one implementation. for demo purpose i have develope following code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class MainJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
        Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);
        new Thread(producer).start();
        new Thread(consumer).start();
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = null;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Producer added " + i);
                queue.put(String.valueOf(i));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = null;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumer used " + queue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected behavior**

```
Producer add 0
Consumer used 0
Producer add 1
Consumer used 1 
and so on..
```

**Actaul O/P**

```
Producer added 0
Producer added 1
Consumer used 0
Consumer used 1
Producer added 2
Producer added 3
Producer added 4
```

I tried using debug mode where it is working correctly. So why without debug mode, things don't work properly ?

Comment: This is happening because your two threads are running parallel to each other ! You can't predicted their behavior !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Actually he has a blocking queue of size one, so one will always be waiting. The "problem" here is that he's trusting the output of System.out.println to determine whether it's working correctly or not, which isn't reliable.

Comment: my two threads uses a que where one adds item other remove it , when producer adds one item and then try to add another item it should block , and when que is empty consumer should be blocked until item is added to queue .. this is for what we can use BlockingQueue right?

Comment: @Kayaman But, he has two separate blocking queues ! :)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha No he doesn't. There's only one `new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1);` in the code.

Comment: i have passed the same instance to two thread in constructor

Comment: In this case, @Kayaman answer might be correct ! But I was not aware of `System.out.println` strange behaviour !

Comment: This is one of those cases where running in debug mode, or reorganizing the lines of code can affect the output. The platform can affect this also, since it depends on native functionality.

Comment: @Kayaman if that is the case then assuming the **System.out.println** is our actual work on object in queue will also be out of synch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as it should - it is just an 'illusion' that your queue seems to contain more than one item at a time caused by unlucky timing and a `System.out.println` at the wrong place:

In your producer, the `System.out.println` comes before the blocking `put`, so you're printing 'Producer added x' even if `put` has to wait until the queue gets empty.

But even if we exchange these two lines (having the `put` coming before `System.out.println`),  the output seems wrong:

```
Consumer used 0
Producer added 0
Producer added 1
Consumer used 1
Consumer used 2
Producer added 2
Producer added 3
Consumer used 3
```

Still, this is an illusion caused by unlucky timing. As you can see, in my output, the consumer seems to consume element 0 **before** the producer put it into the queue! This is of course not the case. `System.out` is a `PrintStream` object, which is thread-safe. So only one thread can print something at the same time. In the run above, the consumer thread simply grabbed the lock before the producer.

The order of execution might be something like that:

1. Producer: `put 0 into queue`
2. Consumer: `take 0 from queue`
3. Consumer: `print 'Consumer used 0'`
4. Consumer: `wait until queue not empty`
5. Producer: `print 'Producer added 0'`
6. Producer: `put 1 into queue`
7. Producer: `print 'Producer added 1'`
8. Producer: `wait until queue not full`
9. Consumer: `take 1 from queue`
10. Consumer: `print 'Consumer used 1'`
11. Producer: `put 2 into queue`
12. Consumer: `take 2 from queue`
13. Consumer: `print 'Consumer used 2'`
14. Producer: `print 'Producer added 2'`

etc.

It is very difficult in multi threaded systems to argue about correct behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

@Kayaman actually already answered the question, but maybe a bit more information may be helpful here.

> EDIT ... and isnot2bad wrote a similar answer (+1). I'm obviously too slow. However, maybe it is considered useful nevertheless.

First of all: The code

```
System.out.println("Producer added " + i);
queue.put(String.valueOf(i));
```

will obviously print `Producer added 1` **before** it was actually added to the queue. Simply swapping the lines to

```
queue.put(String.valueOf(i));
System.out.println("Producer added " + i);
```

will reduce the number of cases where the output seems to be wrong, but not eliminate them completely. The reason is that these two lines are not *atomic*.

An example schedule that shows what each thread is doing at each step shows that the result may look arbitrarily wrong, depending on the order of operations:

```
Producer thread:          Consumer thread:           Queue:      Output:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
queue.put(0);                                        [0]
println("Added " + 0);                               []          Added 0
                          String 0 = queue.take();   []
                          println("Used  " + 0);     []          Used 0 
queue.put(1);                                        [1]         
                          String 1 = queue.take();   []
println("Added " + 1);                               []          Added 1
queue.put(2);                                        [2]         
println("Added " + 2);                               [2]         Added 2
                          println("Used  " + 1);     [2]         Used 1 
                          String 2 = queue.take();   []
                          println("Used  " + 2);     []          Used 2 
queue.put(3);                                        [3]         
                          String 3 = queue.take();   []
                          println("Used  " + 3);     []          Used 3 
println("Added " + 3);                               []          Added 3
queue.put(4);                                        [4]         
println("Added " + 4);                               [4]         Added 4
```

Still, the key point is that the queue never contains more than one element.

Comment: +1 Nice timing table! You could even parallelize certain steps, e.g. the first 6 steps of the producer could be carried out in one flow (without empty lines), while the consumer executes its first three steps in one block (with one step delay).